# How to detect correct type for a variable in Typescript when types are conditional

Tags: node.js, typescript

The code is like this:

```
class MyClass {
  getValue() {
    // some code here...
  }
}

const IS_ENABLED = process.env.IS_ENABLED || false;
const myClass = IS_ENABLED ? new MyClass() : null;

function getValue() {
  if (!IS_ENABLED) return false;

  return myClass.getValue();
}
```

Now at this point, TypeScript is giving error (for myClass.getValue()):

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
```

But, since I've checked the condition, I'm sure it's not null.

Is there any way for TypeScript to handle it?

Comment: I tried to reproduce [your code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getValue()%20%7B%20return%20123%3B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20IS_ENABLED%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myClass%20%3D%20IS_ENABLED%20%3F%20new%20MyClass()%20%3A%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getValue()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(!IS_ENABLED)%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20myClass.getValue()%3B%0D%0A%7D) , but I can't see the error.

Comment: @YakovFain That's probably because I had not defined MyClass in my code.
I have done that.

Also, I'm using strict checking in my 'tsconfig.json'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will not keep track of variables that are related in this way. There are a number of patterns that act as type guards and change the type of a variable.

In this case since `IS_ENABLED` and `myClass` are very much related, you can just check the if `myClass` is `undefined`.

```
const IS_ENABLED = process.env.IS_ENABLED || false;
const myClass = IS_ENABLED ? new MyClass() : null;

function getValue() {
    if (!myClass) return false;

    return myClass.getValue();
}
```

Or you could use a discriminated union (this might be useful if you have multiple `myClass` type like varaibles):

```
const config = (process.env.IS_ENABLED || false) ? {
    IS_ENABLED: true as const,
    myClass: new MyClass(),
    myClass2: new MyClass()
} : {
    IS_ENABLED: false as const,
}

function getValue() {
    if (!config.IS_ENABLED) return false;
    config.myClass2.getValue();
    return config.myClass.getValue();
}
```

Comment: 1st example works. Yet I was expecting better from TypeScript to detect the type.

Answer (score 0):

Type Guards allow you to narrow down the type of an object within a conditional block.
You can use `instanceof` to make Typescript knows its type.

```
const IS_ENABLED = process.env.IS_ENABLED || false;
const myClass = IS_ENABLED ? new MyClass() : null;

function getValue() {
  if (!IS_ENABLED) return false;
  if (myClass instanceof MyClass) {
    return myClass.getValue();
  }
  return false;
}
```

For details please check [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html).